# Create boot disk clone\image from OS

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, backup

I have disk with Windows Server 2008 R2. I want to create image\clone of this disk. I want to be able to do that from OS.

So I want to clone disk I am currently booted from to another disk. Then I want to boot from this cloned disk.

Is it possible to make bootable disk image\clone from OS level ? What is the best way\tool to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first solutions : you can use [Hirens Tool or Norton Ghost](http://www.hirensbootcd.org/hbcd-v105/) or Acronis True image
or [G4L Ghost 4 Linux 0.34a](http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd)

second : you cant use from standard solutions and tools that Microsoft suggested

like sysprep.exe , [imagex.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722145%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) to create WIM IMAGE
attend and unattend installation, WDS , SCCM

third : use another virtualization like [vmware vsphere (ESXi5) to clone](http://www.google.com/search?q=vsphere%20clone) ...

Comment: +1 Acronis True Image looks fine. Just read on Wiki "The program can back up a system hard drive while the OS is running".

Comment: ok thanks. but with hirens boot cd version 10 you can find bootable version of that.

Comment: @ saber tabatabaee yazdi : True Image is not for Windows Server just for workstation.